# How can I add two elements to plotLayer using cnFreq?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have the following code, which works nicely:

```
A1_Plot <- cnFreq(cnData3.1_A1, genome= "hg19", CN_low_cutoff = -0.2, CN_high_cutoff = 0.2,
              x_title_size = NULL,
              y_title_size = NULL,
              plotLayer = ylab(" "),
              plot_title = ("A1"))
```

How can I add an xlab definition as well? Ive tried the following:

```
A1_Plot <- cnFreq(cnData3.1_A1, genome= "hg19", CN_low_cutoff = -0.2, CN_high_cutoff = 0.2,
              x_title_size = NULL,
              y_title_size = NULL,
              plotLayer = c(ylab(" "), xlab(" ")),
              plot_title = ("A1"))
```

But I get an error as follows:

```
Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
```

I'm trying to remove the X and Y axis from the cnFreq plot.

Update: I've also tried the following based on recommended topics:

```
A1_Plot <- cnFreq(cnData3.1_A1, genome= "hg19", CN_low_cutoff = -0.2, 
CN_high_cutoff = 0.2,
              x_title_size = 0,
              y_title_size = NULL,
              plotLayer = ylab(" ") +
                xlab(" "),
              plot_title = ("A1 Subgroup"))
```

Gives this

```
Error in ylab(" ") + xlab(" ") : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I'm new, be gentle.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the answer in my travels. The solution is to edit the plot after it is produced using facet_grid, which can have plotlayers added into it. It doesn't really matter what the x and y labels are, you can use plotlayer to change them. Below I took my A1 plot, fixed the facets, then added the alteration of the X and Y labels onto it. It is easier to affect the change after the plot is produced rather than while producing it. Not sure if this is the most efficient mechanism, but it works.

```
A1_Plot2 <- A1_Plot + facet_grid(.~chromosome, 
                             space = "free", 
                             scales = "free", 
                             labeller = as_labeller(Usechromosomes)) + 
(plotlayer = xlab(" ")) + (plotlayer = ylab(" "))
```